# Точный таймер обратного отсчёта на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, таймер

```
private DispatcherTimer _timer; // таймер главных часов
private TimeSpan _timeToZero; // таймер главных часов
private readonly TimeSpan _intervalToSubstract = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-15);

    private void setTimerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int secToCountDown = 20;


            if (_timer != null)
                _timer.Stop();
            StartPauseBtn.Content = "Start";

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer ( DispatcherPriority.Send );
            _timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15);
            _timeToZero = new TimeSpan(0, 0, secToCountDown, 0, 0);
         xamOsnVr.Text = _timeToZero.ToString("mm\\:ss");

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_timeToZero > TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                _timeToZero -= _timeToZero.Add(_intervalToSubstract);
                //pereriv1 = _timeToZero.ToString("mm\\:ss");
               if (_timeToZero > short_opros)
               {
                   xamOsnVr.Text = _timeToZero.ToString("mm\\:ss");

        else
              {
                   xamOsnVr.Text = _timeToZero.ToString("ss\\.ff");
```

Есть приложение для показа таймера на 20 минут обратного отсчёта на `WPF` (`mm\\:ss`). При использовании разрешения в 1 секунду идут точно. но встала задачка чтобы при остатке менее 1 минуты показ шел (`ss\\.ff`). Пробовал `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-15)` точности не могу добиться то убегают, то опаздывают. Разница в 6-7 секунд на 20 минут. Я думал уже 2 таймера приделать, но как заставить их  работать на 1 `timer_Tick`. таймер стандартный для `WPF`

Comment: А покажите ваш код, а?

Comment: При старте отчета запоминаете время окончания`dateTimeEnd = DateTime.Now + <смещение>`, запускаете таймер с нужным интервалом и при каждом "тике" получаете остаток `dateTimeEnd - DateTime.Now`

Comment: Спасибо за идею но таймер управляемый, в течении 20 минут нужно останавливать и продолжать отсчёт.

Comment: Есть другой вариант. До остатка в 1 минуту идёт основной таймер после дополнительный для вывода милисекунд. но как объединить 2 в  одном?

Comment: Зачем? Сделайте биндинг остатка в какому-нибудь `TextBox` через конвертер, который будет проверять сколько осталось и отдавать остаток в нужном формате

Comment: Маленькая проблемка. с биндингом не дружу

Comment: @MihailMihailenko: А вот это зря. Подружитесь, это центральный и практически основной инструмент в WPF. Вы же не пишете на WPF как на WinForms, надеюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программа тупит, отсюда и отставания. Вы отнимаете интервал срабатывания таймера, а надо отталкиваться от текущей даты и даты запуска таймера, тогда вы точно будете знать, сколько прошло времени с момента запуска таймера.

Вот код

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace TestAny
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для Wnd_Timer.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Wnd_Timer : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTime _startCountdown; // время запуска таймера
        private TimeSpan _startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); // начальное время до окончания таймера
        private TimeSpan _timeToEnd; // время до окончания таймера. Меняется когда таймер запущен
        private TimeSpan _interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15); // интервал таймера
        private DateTime _pauseTime;


        private DispatcherTimer _timer;

        public Wnd_Timer()
        {
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _timer.Interval = _interval;
            _timer.Tick += delegate
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                var elapsed = now.Subtract(_startCountdown);
                TimeToEnd = _startTimeSpan.Subtract(elapsed);
            };
            StopTimer();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public TimeSpan TimeToEnd
        {
            get
            {
                return _timeToEnd;
            }

            set
            {
                _timeToEnd = value;
                if (value.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
                {
                    StopTimer();
                    // тут ваши действия при окончании таймера
                }

                OnPropertyChanged("StringCountdown");
            }
        }

        public string StringCountdown
        {
            get
            {
                var frmt = TimeToEnd.Minutes < 1 ? "ss\\.ff" : "mm\\:ss";
                return _timeToEnd.ToString(frmt);
            }
        }

        public bool TimerIsEnabled
        {
            get { return _timer.IsEnabled; }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private void StopTimer()
        {
            if (TimerIsEnabled)
                _timer.Stop();
            TimeToEnd = _startTimeSpan;
        }

        private void StartTimer(DateTime sDate)
        {
            _startCountdown = sDate;
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void PauseTimer()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _pauseTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

        private void ReleaseTimer()
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var elapsed = now.Subtract(_pauseTime);
            _startCountdown = _startCountdown.Add(elapsed);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartTimer(DateTime.Now);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StopTimer();
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PauseTimer();
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestAny.Wnd_Timer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAny"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Wnd_Timer" Height="300" Width="300"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringCountdown}" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Content="Start" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <Button Content="Null" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
                <Button Content="Pause" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
                <Button Content="Release" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Конвертер присутствует в коде if (_timeToZero > short_opros)
               {
                   xamOsnVr.Text = _timeToZero.ToString("mm\\:ss");

        else
              {
                   xamOsnVr.Text = _timeToZero.ToString("ss\\.ff");

Comment: @MihailMihailenko, поправил. Это можно копипастить. Все работает без отставаний

Comment: Всё работает если не останавливать. Но задача была чтобы во время работы таймера можно было остановить когда нужно и потом продолжить.

Comment: @MihailMihailenko, о таких вещах лучше говорить сразу. Поправил. Теперь можно ставить на паузу (Pause) и возобновлять (Release)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё окей.

Answer (score 2):

Точного таймера нет ни в WPF, ни в любой другой библиотеке по одной простой причине — точный таймер может быть только в системе реального времени, все остальные таймеры срабатывают примерно через тот интервал, что им задан. Единственная гарантия, которую, как правило, дают таймеры это то, что таймер сработает не раньше, чем через тот промежуток времени, который ему задали.

Чтобы повысить точность, необходимо на каждом тике корректировать интервал на который Вы выставляете таймер, или же корректировать Ваш обратный отсчёт. Т.е. из обратного отсчёта Вы будете вычитать не одну секунду всегда, а реальное количество секунд(миллисекунд), которое прошло с последнего тика.

---

В коде это сделать довольно просто, для начала заведём в классе переменную, которая будет содержать время, когда таймер был запущен(или же сработал):

```
private DateTime m_LastTimeFired;
```

В коде, где мы запускаем таймер, после того как сделали ему старт делаем:

```
m_LastTimeFired = DateTime.Now;
```

Потом в обработчике, который вызывается на каждый тик таймера, пишем следующее:

```
...
var elapsed = DateTime.Now - m_LastTimeFired;
m_LastTimeFired = DateTime.Now;
_timeToZero -= elapsed;
...
```

P.S. Код не проверял, может где опечатался

Comment: а есть где почитать про такой механизм?

Comment: @MihailMihailenko, да тут читать нечего. Если не понимаете того, что я написал, могу кодом накидать(или псевдокодом)

Comment: если не сложно можно кодом, применительно к этому проэкту.

Comment: @MihailMihailenko, добавил